# Sluggish resize performance with lots of DIVs

Tags: html, css, browser, resize

I display a grid of dots for a small puzzle game with.
That script isn't quite correct yet, but that's not the issue.

The issue is that **with all these divs, resizing the browser window is very sluggish**. That's despite not doing things like redrawing/repositioning the elements at resize time.

Tried it in both Safari and Chrome.
Tried it with `grid` as well, same result as with absolute positioning.

**Needs a large window for enough divs (~5000) to be generated for the issue to show up.**

Are we just not supposed to have this many divs? Is there a way to optimise this? Maybe an alternative solution for having a large grid of elements?

Using three.js feels very much overkill for what I'm trying to accomplish.

Thank you.

*EDIT: Here's a JSBin example where you can try and maximise the window (then rerun) for the issue to manifest. The `alert` shows the number of divs generated. https://jsbin.com/zurojakese/edit?output.*

```js
let size = 10
let gap = 10
let cols = (window.innerWidth - gap) / (size + gap)
let rows = (window.innerHeight - gap) / (size + gap)
let col = 0
let row = 0
for (let i = 0; i < cols * rows; i++) {

  let div = document.createElement('div')
  document.body.appendChild(div)

  div.style.top = gap + row * (gap + size) + 'px'
  div.style.left = (row % 2 == 0 ? gap : 0) + gap + col * (gap + size) + 'px'
  div.style.animationDelay = (0.25 * i) + 's'

  col += 1
  if (col > cols) {
    col = 0;
    row += 1
  }
}
```

```css
div {
  position: absolute;
  background: #adadad;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
```

Comment: I created a codepen with this and it seems the `border-radius` is the culprit. Without it your output is no longer sluggish.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @RenevanderLende, but it seems like resizing isn't sluggish in CodePen even with border-radius. Interesting find! I noticed their preview area is done with an iframe, that might have something to do with it 

Comment: @RenevanderLende never mind, it was just because I had a smaller window and so there weren't that many divs generated :)

Comment: *"overkill for what I'm trying to accomplish"* and what is that you're trying to accomplish? Could you provide a [mcve] of your issue?

Comment: Why not draw them as a repeating background in one div, and if you want to know which one is, say, clicked, then do it by cursor position as it's a regular pattern.

Comment: @isherwood Thanks for the attention. I wrote in my post before it was edited out that the problem only occurs if the window is big enough for a lot of divs to be generated (around 5k). The problem won't shop up in the tiny SO preview window. https://jsbin.com/zurojakese/edit?output Make the window as big as you can, refresh and you'll see the sluggish resizing.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan Literally just what is in my post. The user will be able to manipulate the divs later, but for now, I'd just like to display the divs and maintain good perf when resizing. Please see my previous comment for a jsbin example that helps surface the problem.

Comment: @AHaworth I'd like to do transforms and animations on the divs with user interaction, so going the background route doesn't work I think.

Comment: Do you need them there all the time? It depends on what sort of interaction, but at it's simplest you could create a div when needed - but whether this is useful depends on what sort of interaction and over how many dots etc. Or have the background and the divs transparent and non-circular to begin with.

Comment: @AHaworth For this specific puzzle, they need all need to be there until it's solved. There's going to be `transform` and/or `width/height` changes, `opacity`, etc.. applied to the divs based on click and/or mouse movement. Some might disappear, etc... but generally speaking I'd like the full page to be covered by them. Whether or not they are circular does not seem to have effect the resizing perf. Have you been able to reproduce it with the jsbin link?

Comment: I don't see any pause when resize.

Comment: @AHaworth could you please tell me how many divs are generated? the jsbin example will pop up the number

Comment: you should use canvas js for things like this

Comment: I tested on an 11 year old laptop, latest version of Chrome, Windows 10, **6100** elements - absolutely NO performance issue. Then I enabled the Windows' "show window contents while dragging" setting and the performance was slightly but somewhat noticeably worse. Not a Chrome/JavaScript/CSS issue.

Comment: @SalmanA Wow that's really interesting! It even lags (and badly) on a gaming PC for me (Win 11, Firefox) with around 6k elements. It's not a dragging things though, it's a window resize thing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This issue occurs because the browser is conducting multiple layout computations and repaints on the page during the resize operation.

On window resize, the browser typically conducts a full [reflow](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Reflow) and repaint of the DOM. Reflow is a very expensive process, particularly for a large number of nodes. (In your case the nodes have been positioned absolutely, so they will not have the full reflow operation performed, but will still have layout computations done on each.) Repainting is a subsequent operation that also occurs, and while much faster than reflow or layout computation, still adds to the computation time needed on a window resize. Reflow, layout computations, and repaints are user blocking processes: that is, user interaction will be interrupted while it occurs and it will be conducted synchronously.

While some reflows, such as those triggered by JavaScript on a specific element, can be conducted on a subset of nodes, a window resize can be expected to trigger reflow (or layout computation for fixed and absolute elements) for all displayed nodes in the DOM. It's not unreasonable for a reflow of > 5000 nodes to take longer than a frame (16ms) on some hardware. Dragging a window border to resize will trigger a very rapid series of reflows that are all blocking, so it's to be expected that you're seeing performance issues.

Browsers do have some optimisations to minimise unnecessary reflows, but unfortunately it seems like you might be out of luck. However, there are two possible workarounds for your issue.

### 1. Hide nodes during the resize process.

Setting `display: none` will remove an element and its children from reflow calculations. On the first occurrence of a `resize` event, set the outermost element to `display: none` to hide the game. Reflow calculations should be drastically sped up. Once resizing has finished, set `display: block` (or whatever the original `display` value was). You can adapt a debounce function to determine when resizing has completed - I find that 50ms without a new `resize` event is a good indicator that the user has stopped resizing.

This will obviously mean a blank screen while resizing is happening. For a more seamless look you may want to show a notice during the resize process. Or you could use a library such as [html2canvas](https://www.npmjs.com/package/html2canvas) to take a screenshot of the page immediately prior to deleting the game elements, and show that during resizing. Note that with such a large number of nodes, using html2canvas may cause an initial lag while it captures the image.

### 2. Use Canvas

Running a game with thousands of HTML nodes is certainly pushing the limits of what HTML was intended for. Using HTML Canvas is likely a more suitable approach, although it sounds like it'll require significant reworking of your code. You can control every occasion that a canvas redraw is done, so a window resizing does not require any redraws. There are many other benefits to using Canvas for a game, such as it using the GPU rather than CPU to draw, but that's beyond the scope of this question.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation @jla! Seems like the html2canvas idea was implemented by alex in another answer and has the drawback you mentioned. But you did give me an idea of maybe hiding enough of the dots (in some pattern) for the duration of the resize so that it won't be laggy. That could even look interesting. The notice is a good idea too. Although not the solution I hoped for, your answer was the most illuminating, so I'll give you the bounty. Cheers!

Comment: dam i latterly implemented  it via code jla just explained my code this is very unfair

Comment: @alexhernandez Please don't be upset, I didn't accept this answer because the html2canvas solution works (cause it doesn't). I accepted it, because of the idea of hiding the nodes (or a number of nodes) during the resize process.

Comment: @alexhernandez Oh, I just realised you implemented the hiding as well. I'm sorry, it was still jla's explanation that was more illuminative to me. I was thrown off by the experience that in your solution there is a big lag that happens at the start of resizing (and also there's the seam when enlarging) due to the use html2canvas. Plus, the 2 second timer was also threw me off and made me not think about hiding the divs more seriously, until jla's answer kinda lead me to the realisation that I can simply do the hiding for the resize duration and no longer.

Comment: its all good i appreciate the response and this method may not give you a smooth resizing as you seen on my old code and i would say the the best way to have smooth resizing is to make the object not react on resizing until user stop resizing for around 2 second or adjust as needed. I would even say to use three.js or webgl for the best performance.

Comment: All elements are absolutely positioned. There is no reflow. Sorry.

Comment: @SalmanA I understood that if the dimensions of the parent of an absolutely positioned element change, that will still trigger layout computations for the child (eg if the child has `right: 0`, and the parent's width changes, then the child's location will change). In this case the window dimensions are changing so layout must be re-computed for children. Is that not so? https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/insights/browser-reflow indicates that window resizing does trigger reflow

Answer (score 1):

There is indeed a Limit, it's a mere suggestion by Google to avoid an excessive DOM size. But to many divs will have a great impact on the performance.
Ligthouse suggest only a max of 1400 nodes. From my experince a web page with more than 2k nodes will work fine.
But an excessive amount will have a noticeable lose of performance.
The exact amount of nodes will be different for each user, after which the performance will slow down.

https://developer.chrome.com/docs/lighthouse/performance/dom-size/

If you want to draw an interactive background like this i would suggest to look into how to draw Canvas. As an alternative approach webgl offers the power to utilize enhanced rendering quallities for your game.

Comment: Thanks Florian. I did read about the excessive DOM size warning earlier, but I kinda figured that since my layout is pretty flat and there's almost no complexity, I should be able to get away with much more divs. I'm just so surprised that a browser cannot even handle 4-5k simple grey dots without lagging when resizing. I guess I'm looking for some way to do hardware acceleration but without using a game engine, because that would increase the project complexity considerably.

Answer (score 0):

the program should not give you constant lag but lag may still exist depending on your computer, but i made it were when resizing the screen it should hide the balls until you stop resizing the screen for 2 seconds you could adjust the time . also i don't recommend running it here in stack overflow causes extra lag just run it in this website instead https://500.alexhernandez11.repl.co

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>5000 Balls Example</title>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html2canvas/0.5.0-beta4/html2canvas.min.js"></script>
    <style>
    
    .container {
        position: absolute;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        background-color: black;
    top: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    }
    
    body {
        margin: 0px;
        height: 100%;
    }
    
        .ball {
            width: 20px;
            height: 20px;
            border-radius: 50%;
            position: absolute;
            background-color: gray;
            animation: move 1s infinite linear;
            opacity: 0.7;
        }
    
        @keyframes move {
            0% {
                transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(0deg) translateX(50%);
            }
            50% {
                transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(180deg) translateX(50%);
            }
            100% {
                transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(360deg) translateX(50%);
            }
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <span id="width"></span><br>
    <span id="height"></span>
    
    <div class="container">
        <!-- Generate balls with JS -->
    </div>
    
    

    
    <script>
        function generate_balls() {
          // Generate balls
          const numBalls = 5000;
          const container = document.querySelector('.container');
          for (let i = 0; i < numBalls; i++) {
            const ball = document.createElement('div');
            ball.className = 'ball';
            ball.style.left = `${Math.random() * 100}%`;
            ball.style.top = `${Math.random() * 100}%`;
            container.appendChild(ball);
          }
        }

        function takeScreenshot() {
            html2canvas(document.querySelector(".container")).then(canvas => {
            imgData = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
            document.body.style.backgroundImage = `url(${imgData})`;
            });
        }

        let isResizing = false;
        let timeoutId = null;
        const myDiv = document.querySelector('.container');
        
        function resizeHandler() {
          isResizing = true;
          document.getElementById('width').textContent = window.innerWidth;
          document.getElementById('height').textContent = window.innerHeight;
          console.log("Resizing started");
        
          // this will remove the ball until resizing finsihed
          
         
          myDiv.style.display = "none"; // Hide the container
          //myDiv.style.display = imgData; 
          
          if (timeoutId) {
            clearTimeout(timeoutId);
          }
        
          timeoutId = setTimeout(function() {
            isResizing = false;
            timeoutId = null;
            console.log("Resizing finished");
        
            myDiv.style.display = "block"; // Show the container
            
          }, 2 * 1000); // Set timeout duration in seconds (1 second in this example)
        }
    
        window.addEventListener('resize', resizeHandler);
        
        generate_balls();
        takeScreenshot()
        
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks Alex! My problem isn't that the dots don't rearrange themselves on resize, I can handle that later. My problem is that when resizing, the performance is abysmal if too many dots are generated (~5k). This happens with both of your examples as well. Run the snippet, click the "Full page" button and resize your browser window to take up all the screen. Do this on at least a 15" screen (but preferably higher) and try resizing the window. It'll lag and the lag is proportionate to how many dots there are.

Comment: i found a simple solution

Comment: Thanks for the effort Alex! Unfortunately, with this attempt, there's a big lag when the resize begins (which in my opinion is ultimately not better than a generally laggy resize), plus if you enlarge the window instead of shrinking it, there's a very visible seam where the pattern repeats.

Comment: your last option would be to use a webgl which is the most opimzise way to render object and runs on your gpu instead of cpu and i think div are based on cpu no sure but the only downside to webgl its very complicated i dont even know its even possible to have a smooths resizing with 5000 divs due to cpu limits and js is not a complied language making it slower another options to make it were the divs have no affect to resizing until user stop resizing for around 2 seconds similar to my old code .

Answer (score 0):

The for cycle is too long, and it has a lot of micro tasks, instead of that, you could try to move some logic to css.

CSS executes a lot faster than javascript, and style definitions should be setted via CSS

Here I tried something different, I think executes a lot faster than your original code

Note: but if you are trying to do a game with a lot of elements, the better option is to use canvas (like Google Sheets with a lot of elements) and build up your game in that base.
Maybe you could give a try to a library like these: https://github.com/collections/javascript-game-engines

```js
    const start = Date.now();
    console.log('start execution', start);

    const size = 10;
    const gap = 10;
    const cols = (window.innerWidth - gap) / (size + gap);
    const rows = (window.innerHeight - gap) / (size + gap);

    const container = document.querySelector('.dots-container');

    const row = document.createElement('div');

    for (let col = 0; col < cols; col++) {
        row.className = "row-dots";
        const dot = document.createElement('div');
        dot.className = "dot";
        row.appendChild(dot);
    }

    const rowOdd = row.cloneNode(true);
    rowOdd.lastChild.remove();
    rowOdd.className = "row-odd-dots";

    for (let rowCount = 0; rowCount < rows; rowCount++) {
        if (rowCount % 2 === 0) {
            container.appendChild(row.cloneNode(true));
        } else {
            container.appendChild(rowOdd.cloneNode(true));
        }
    }

    const end = Date.now();
    console.log('end execution', end, 'total', end - start);
```

```css
.dots-container {
    display: flex;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    gap: 10px;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.dots-container .dot {
    background-color: #adadad;
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    border-radius: 999rem;
    display: flex;
}

.dots-container .row-dots,
.dots-container .row-odd-dots {
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
    gap: 10px;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="dots-container"></div>
```

Performance:

Your original implementation: between 2, 3 and 4 miliseconds (3 and 4 on most runs)
Mine proposal: always between 0 and 1 milisecond

If you are running this function inside a window resize callback, add a dobounce like function to execute it like every 100ms or something similar.

Check it adding logs at the beginning and at the end

Hope that helps, good luck!

[image]

[image]